# splash screen in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I want to create a splash screen in cordova and at the same time while loading splash screen I want to call web services in background. so is this feasible in cordova ? I am new to cordova.Please let me know if there is any possibilities .Thanks in advance .

Comment: follow this link it will help you -http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, put your splash screen images under res/drawable folders. To show splash screen add below line before loadUrl, in your ProjectName.java class(the one extending CordovaActivity).

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen); //R.drawable.your_image_name
```

From that point you have two options.

1. Show splashscreen for fixed amount of time:

   `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000); //this will show 3sec`
2. Do something in JavaScript then close splash manually, call loadUrl without timeout. You can call below anytime in your JS code to close splashscreen:

   `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`